# OFFSET x LIMIT y messed up order of rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one named `sale` and one named `voucher`.
The sale contains a `purchase_date` and the voucher table contains an ID (I'm stripping the irrelevant data from the question).

I am selecting the voucher.ID and the sale.purchase_date from the database and then I order them by date descending.

```
select  voucher.id, sale.purchase_date
    from  voucher
    inner join  sale  ON sale.id=voucher.sale
    order by  sale.purchase_date desc;
```

This goes fine:
[image: SQL selection]

But I am getting a lot of rows as results. To avoid having a slow initial loading time on my webpage I want to load the results in pieces of five. For this, I use the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` commando in MySQL.

```
select  voucher.id, sale.purchase_date
    from  voucher
    inner join  sale  ON sale.id=voucher.sale
    order by  sale.purchase_date desc
    limit  5 offset 0;
```

This seems to work... But it actually messes up the order.

When doing

- LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0, I expect the IDs: 92, 91, 62, 63, 64 (Based on the picture above)
- LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5, I expect the IDs: 65, 66, 67, 68, 69
- LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10, I expect the IDs: 70, 71, 72, 73, 74
- ...

But instead the rows come back in a different order:
[image: SQL Return]

Somehow the row with id 60 somehow gets fetched in the first 5 results when using offsets and limits.

What is the most correct way to load the results from a query in pieces using offset and limit?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3c9d4/3/0).

Comment: a fiddle would help https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @ChrisStrickland I knew about sites like JSFiddle but never heard of SQLFiddle. Will be making one now.

Comment: dbfiddle.uk has more choices for database/version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused because I am ordering on `purchase_date`. But there are multiple rows who have exactly the same purchase_date. MySQL does not guarantee a consistent order over multiple queries between rows who have the same amount of votes in an order-clause.

Adding another unique column in the order-clause solves the issue.

```
select  voucher.id, sale.purchase_date
    from  voucher
    inner join  sale  ON sale.id=voucher.sale
    order by  sale.purchase_date desc, voucher.id desc
    limit  x offset y;
```

Comment: That solves the issue being asked about.  Usually there are two more issues when paginating -- speed and inconsistent output when the data is changing.  Both are discussed here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination